# How do I thin an abandoned Time Machine backup?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I have a NAS with multiple computers' Time Machine backups. Most of these are abandoned, old computers that I don't have anymore. I want to keep the backups—or at least, the latest copies of files—and trim the intermediate backups.

I know I can do this for my current computer with `tmutil thinlocalsnapshots` (although I'm unsure about the specific syntax).

Can I use `tmutil` to thin backups for an abandoned Time Machine bundle unrelated to my current machine?

Comment: There's https://ss64.com/osx/tmutil.html but I wouldn't be confident myself in trying to accurately parse a command just from that.

Comment: @Tetsujin That man page seems outdated, it doesn't mention `thinlocalsnapshots` verb that is in the man page (on my Ventura 13.4). I can't find a `thinlocalbackups` anywhere though.

Comment: Hmm… OK. I can't check Ventura.

Comment: That's a typo on my part; `thinlocalsnapshots` is what I meant. Updating question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did not manage to do this.

We ended up taking the alternative $60 approach, "move the backup to another drive and avoid thinking about the root problem":

1. Pay $60 for a 2TB hard drive
2. Plug it into one of our computers
3. Mounting both our Time Capsule and the new drive,
4. Copy the `.sparsebundle` over to the new drive.

   - Since the Time Capsule is really slow an unreliable, I recommend `rsync`
   - eg `rsync -avzP /path/to/timemachine/foo.sparsebundle /path/to/newdrive` to clone the data over
5. Delete the `.sparsebundle` on the Time Capsule

   - `sudo rm -rf /path/to/timemachine/foo.sparsebundle`
   - Sudo is required since some of these files are locked